# i can't extract last pages content, can some one debug?

Tags: python, debugging, pdf

I am trying to convert pdf into two lists: titles and content. but i find this function is not working for **pdf last pages**.

```
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages
from pdfminer.layout import LTTextContainer,LTChar
#pdf--> title list and content list 
def extract_title_content(path):
    title=[]
    content=[]
    a=""
    b=""   
    mode,minn= check_size(path)
    for page_layout in extract_pages(path):
        title.append(a)
        content.append(b)
        a=""
        b=""           
        for element in page_layout:
            if isinstance(element, LTTextContainer):
                for text_line in element:               
                    for character in text_line:
                        if isinstance(character, LTChar):                       
                            if character.size > mode:
                                a+=character.get_text()
                            elif character.size> minn:
                                b+=character.get_text()
                            else:
                                pass  
    return title,content
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your outer loop you first add the recently extracted larger text in `a` to `title` and the medium text in `b` to `content`, then clear `a` and `b`, and then extract new text to `a` and `b`:

```
for page_layout in extract_pages(path):
    title.append(a)
    content.append(b)
    a=""
    b=""           
    [... extract into a and b ...]
```

Thus, what you extract from the last page never is added to `title` and `content`.

To fix this either move the adding of `a` and `b` to `title` and `content` *after* filling `a` and `b`:

```
for page_layout in extract_pages(path):
    [... extract into a and b ...]
    title.append(a)
    content.append(b)
    a=""
    b=""
```

Or, if you do the adding *before* the filling for a reason, explicitly add again after the loop:

```
for page_layout in extract_pages(path):
    title.append(a)
    content.append(b)
    a=""
    b=""           
    [... extract into a and b ...]
title.append(a)
content.append(b)
```

Comment: perfect! thank you very much!